# android map api authorisation fail across multiple dev machines

Tags: google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps-v2

When I run a google map (v2) app I've developed (using debug key) onto my device it works fine. However, if I build/install the same eclipse project on a different computer the map fails to display and I get the following error:

```
10-11 10:59:11.719: E/Google Maps Android API(16682): Authorization failure.  Please see 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start for how to correctly set up 
the map.

10-11 10:59:11.719: E/Google Maps Android API(16682): Ensure that the following correspond 
to what is in the API Console: Package Name: com.example.androidsession8, API Key: 
Certificate Fingerprint: XXXXXXXXX
```

I haven't tried a release key yet, but surely there can't be some kind of link between my computer/eclipse and my api key? if there is, then how do you develop a map app as a team?

Or are you meant to not share keys between developers and each have their own manifest file - and how does it know it's not valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply copy `debug.keystore` from your machine to all other.

It is stored in `~/.android/` or `C:\Users\{user.name}\.android\`.

For debug/release keys, you can have same API key. Just assign another SHA-1;package pair on [API Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/).

You can of course do that for all debug.keystore of every developer, but sending single keystore to others seems like less work than generating SHA-1 and putting that in the API Console.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that. But why does it not work? how does the google map api key in my manifest know it's a different machine when compiled/deployed?

Comment: @Neil debug.keystore is generated on every machine and has a different SHA-1. Paired with API key won't match on Google servers.